# Removing join between double-line column separator in table

Tags: tables

Sorry for the very specific question, I have been struggling with tables a fair amount recently!

I have produced the following table in LaTeX:
[image]
which has the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\renewcommand{\h}{\hline\hline}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[h!] \centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|b{0.17\paperwidth}||b{0.16\paperwidth}|b{0.16\paperwidth}|b{0.16\paperwidth}|b{0.16\paperwidth}|}
\hline   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Title of columns 2-5} \\
\h Column 1                & Column 2        & Column 3      & Column 4        & Column 5 \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The caption of my table}
\label{label}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

(Please ignore the apparently thicker lines as seen between rows 5 and 6, as well as between columns 1 and 2, this is just an issue with my pdf displayer.)

A minor aesthetic change which I would like to make is to remove the joining line between the `||` between column and the multicolumn in the first row; ie, I'd like to go from this:
[image]
to something which looks like this:
[image]

I am aware this is quite a 'lazy' question, however I am totally unfamiliar with LaTeX tables (any suggested reading/watching to help me learn is greatly appreciated as well!), so any help at all would be brilliant. Because of how specific my title was, I was unable to find any similar questions on SE, however if there are any they would also be greatly appreciated (I was also unsure exactly what to tag this post as related to).

Thanks very much! :)

---

NB: often I see peoples' solutions to these problems involve simply redesigning the table in another style; if it is possible please could this be avoided, as this table style is consistent with the aesthetic of my document (I can't be the only one who thinks lines between columns are a good thing...).

Comment: `hhline` package is your friend

Comment: Words from the creator himself! Thanks: I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this question can have an answer for others' future reference, using the `hhline` package, here is the solution I reached:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] \centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|b{0.17\paperwidth}||b{0.16\paperwidth}|b{0.16\paperwidth}|b{0.16\paperwidth}|b{0.16\paperwidth}|}\hhline{-||----}
                  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Title of columns 2-5} \\ \hhline{=b:b:b====}
Column 1                & Column 2        & Column 3      & Column 4        & Column 5 \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline xx                  & xxx             & xxx           & xxx             & xxx \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The caption of my table}
\label{label}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Which gives:
[image]

Thanks very much to David Carlisle for pointing me in the right direction (and indeed writing the package in the first place)!